# What's the difference between dask=parallelized and dask=allowed in xarray's apply_ufunc?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray, numpy-ufunc

In the [xarray documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html) for the function apply_ufunc it says:

```
dask: ‘forbidden’, ‘allowed’ or ‘parallelized’, optional

    How to handle applying to objects containing lazy data in the form of dask arrays:

    ‘forbidden’ (default): raise an error if a dask array is encountered.
    ‘allowed’: pass dask arrays directly on to func.
    ‘parallelized’: automatically parallelize func if any of the inputs are a dask array. 
                    If used, the output_dtypes argument must also be provided. 
                    Multiple output arguments are not yet supported.
```

and in the documentation's page on [Parallel Computing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#automatic-parallelization) then there is a note:

> For the majority of NumPy functions that are already wrapped by dask, it’s usually a better idea to use the pre-existing dask.array function, by using either a pre-existing xarray methods or apply_ufunc() with dask='allowed'. Dask can often have a more efficient implementation that makes use of the specialized structure of a problem, unlike the generic speedups offered by dask='parallelized'.

However, I'm still not clear as to what the difference between these two options is. Does `allowed` still operate on chunks one by one to lower memory usage? Will `allowed` still parallelize if the applied ufunc only uses dask operations? Why does `parallelized` require you to give more information about the ufunc outputs (i.e. the arguments `output_dtypes`, `output_sizes`) than `allowed` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dask='allowed'` means that you're applying a function that *already* knows how to handle dask arrays, e.g., a function written in terms of `dask.array` operations. In most cases, that does indeed mean that the function will operate on chunks one by one to lower memory usage, and will apply the computation in parallel.

`dask='parallelized'` requires more information from the user because it creates its own wrapper that allows the provided function to act on dask arrays, by using low-level dask.array functions like [`atop`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.core.atop). With `dask='parallelized'`, you can provide a function that only knows how to handle NumPy arrays, and `xarray.apply_ufunc` will extend it to handle dask arrays, too.